# How to instal pymedia for python

Tags: python, media

I am new in Ubuntu and new in Python too but aim to write simple app which will play video from file. All I need is through a single key pause/play and simultaneously I want start application as default after run computer (In the future I would like to use it for my home Raspberry Pi project) . Like a good idea came to me use module PyMedia but occured an insurmountable problem with intallation for me. I have tried to follow the instructions on the following pages, but nothing works for me: [pymedia.org](http://pymedia.org/tut/install_src.html), [ubuntu-be.org](http://ubuntu-be.org/en/node/90)...

So first of all, I installed dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libogg-dev
sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev
sudo apt-get install liblame-dev
sudo apt-get install libfaad2-dev
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

If it happened that a package was obsoleted, I raplaced it with a newer version. The problem occurs when I run in the folder *pymedia-1.3.7.3* command:`sudo python setup.py install`. It displays:

```
OGG : not found 
VORBIS : not found 
FAAD : not found 
MP3LAME : not found 
VORBISENC : not found 
ALSA : not found 
Continue building pymedia ? [Y,n]:
```

...which I can not understand. Of course, that following installation ends in failure.

I will be glad for any solution and as well will be grateful for any suggestion of suitable alternative module for my purpose.

Comment: According to its website, PyMedia was last updated in February 2006, over 10 years ago; this could be the reason you're having trouble. Maybe there's an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you are on a 64-bit machine.

change line 226 in setup.py

from lib_hunt = ['/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib' ]

to

lib_hunt = [ '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib' ]

This is to make the script search for libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

Then 
install libfaad-dev which provides faad.h
install libmp3lame-dev which provides  lame.h

this should fix it.

Comment: You are right I have 64-bit system. I replaced the line exactly as you described above but unfortunately without change. Still it hasn't fount any dependencies.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka can you paste output of 'strace python setup.py install'

Comment: I apologize for the mystification. Dependencies are found now just installation goes wrong: